# Why are utf16 / surrogate pairs emojis not displayed correctly in console.log() when run through yarn on Windows? (npm and node directly are fine)

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, console.log, utf-16, surrogate-pairs

Somehow running `console.log('Thunderbirds are go! ')` via yarn / node does not display the emoji but outputs � instead.

I'm on Windows Terminal / Git Bash which in itself has no problems displaying utf-16 surrogate pairs. Running a script through node directly (`node test.js`) as well as through npm (`npm run start` which is defined as `node test.js`) both output the emoji correctly. However running it through yarn results in �:

[image: code screenshot]

Why won't it output the emoji when I run it through yarn? Is there a way to fix it?